# React-router 6 errorElement not rendering an error component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

In my react app I'm trying to render custom error component for unmatched routes but default error page is shown.

This is how my browserRouter looks.

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/feed",
    element: <App />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <Feed />,
      },
      {
        path: "/feed/login",
        element: <Login />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```

P.S. If I have root path as just `'/'` it works fine. But if let's say I want my root path to be `'/feed'` then the error component is not getting rendered.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link, useRouteError } from 'react-router-dom';

const ErrorPage = () => {
  const error = useRouteError()
  
  return (
    <div className='w-full h-screen flex flex-col items-center mt-28'>
      <h1 className='text-8xl text-neutral-grayish-blue'>Error <span className='text-8xl text-primary-soft-red'>{error.status}</span></h1>
      <p className='text-4xl text-neutral-grayish-blue my-10'>{error.statusText}</p>
      <Link to={'/feed'} className='p-2 bg-neutral-dark-blue text-neutral-white rounded-md'>Back Home</Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ErrorPage;
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include `<ErrorPage />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is using the default error boundary component. Remember that errors bubble up. Move the `ErrorPage` error boundary component up higher in the routing tree than the route that generates the error.

Example:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />, // <-- root error component
    children: [
      {
        path: "/feed",
        children: [
          {
            index: true,
            element: <Feed />
          },
          {
            path: "/feed/login",
            element: <Login />
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]);
```

### Demo

Demo sandbox tries to access unknown route `"/foo"`.

[image]

[image: Edit react-router-6-errorelement-not-rendering-an-error-component]

Answer (score 0):

errorElement s not for unmatched routes, for your problem you can add another root object with path * (means anywhere but your created paths) and there add your page

Comment: This resolves my problem but now I don't have access to useRouteError hook (but I can live without that in this particular scenario).

And also in the official react-router page, errorElement is used fot not found pages.

https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial#handling-not-found-errors

Comment: errorElement for not found errors ( for ErrorBoundary component ), for example if you throw new Error() then your errorElement would work